# Join the same table twice

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I'm stuck with a join where I try to join the same table twice.

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](  
   [Account] [nvarchar](10) NULL,  
   [Value] [real] NULL,  
   [Period] [nvarchar](8) NULL)   

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC1', 100, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC2', -100, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC3', 200, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC4', -200, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC1', 100, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC1', -100, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC2', 200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC2', -200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC5', 100, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC5', -100, '201407')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC6', 200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC6', -200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC3', 200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC3', -200, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC7', 300, '201408')  
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('AC8', -300, '201408')
```

The first result which I try to archive is to have all account in the first column and the values for each Period in seperate column. I tried many different join and nothing is working. The last I have is the below but it duplicates me some records for the first Period and does not show some accounts.

```
  SELECT A1.account, A1.value, A2.value FROM Accounts A1   
  FULL OUTER JOIN accounts A2 on A1.account = A2.account  
  WHERE A1.Period = '201407' and A2.period = '201408'
```

The final query I trying to archive should deliver such a result:

```
ACCOUNT P1    P2  
AC1     100   0  
AC2     -100  0  
AC3      200  0  
AC4     -200  NULL  
AC5      0    NULL  
AC6      0    0
AC7     NULL  300
AC8     NULL  -300
```

What I'm doing wrong? I tried all possible join types and neasted selects :(.

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom, a join is not required to achieve the results you're looking for.  Try the following code:

```
select account
    ,P1=sum(case when period = '201407' then value else null end)
    ,P2=sum(case when period = '201408' then value else null end)
from Accounts
where period in ('201407', '201408')
group by account
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast answer.
It is working :)

In the mean time I found also another solution which is also working.
Analysing yours I think it is more efficient then my.

Thank you!

```
select distinct(x.account) konto, a.v1, b.v2 from accounts X 
left join(select account a1, sum(value) v1 from accounts  where Period = '201407' group by account) a on a.a1 = x.account
left join(select account a2, sum(value) v2 from accounts  where Period = '201408' group by account) b on b.a2 = x.account
```